# How to map what I see in "Ubuntu Software" to dpkg/apt entries?

Tags: software-center

I see an application "Document Viewer" in the "Installed" section of "Ubuntu Software". I would like to know what binary file is being called, or what entry in dkpg/snap/apt is being referenced (is it "docview"? "doc_view"? "docviewer"?) when I click on this, so that I can locate the entry using tools like dpkg/apt/snap and see what it's pointing too.

All answers I get on the web for similar questions point to using dpkg/apt/snap - for all those cases, the package name cannot contain spaces and is normalized.

Something like doing (on Windows) - a right click in Programs -> MyApp -> Details -> Program file (which shows you the location of the .exe that is being pointed to).

Comment: Ubuntu Software is meant to be a deliberately-simple human-readable (not machine-readable) application. All mapping takes place under the hood and is deliberately not exposed to the user. Folks who want to watch the gears turn should use a different tool. My uncle likes Ubuntu Software *precisely* because it doesn't present a lot of irrelevant (to him) details.

Comment: There's `apt-cache search`, `dpkg  -S /path/to/file` and `locate`. Read `man apt-cache dpkg locate updatedb`.

Comment: @user535733 .. the 2 scenarios are not mutually exclusive. Your uncle will still like Ubuntu if there was an answer to my question.

It turns out that I need to get under the hood precisely because Ubuntu is not uncle-friendly enough. I'm trying to open a pdf file in Thunderbird Email and it's asking me for a path to the application I would like to use, which is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: If you are asking "Is there an existing way to expose this in Ubuntu Software" the clear answer is "No". If you are asking "Can somebody develop this feature to be be added to Ubuntu Software?" that's a feature request that you should make directly to the Gnome Developers (who don't hang out here). If you are offering "I hacked the source code and wrote a patch that exposes this feature, and I will maintain that patch," then the Ubuntu Desktop Team may also be interested.

Comment: The usual Gnome PDF reader is /usr/bin/evince. That connection between Thunderbird and Evince should already be set up if you installed from a normal Ubuntu Desktop installer. The folks who encounter that kind of  Thunderbird hiccup typically installed from Minimal or Server.

Comment: No..I'm a "folk" who installed Regular Desktop Ubuntu from the the regular channels. Installed Thunderbird the usual way using Ubuntu Software. The association is not set up. Even ifthe association was not set up on installing Minimal Ubuntu, I would still be here on StackExchange asking the same question. Minimal != Broken. Something has failed along the way. The reason to expose plumbing to advanced users is exactly so I don't have to spend the next 6 months finding out whose fault at Canonical this was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till a better answer is found ...
The software list one sees in the `Installed` tab of `Ubuntu Software` seems to come from `*.desktop` files in the folder `/usr/share/applications`. Grepping this folder for the relevant entry:

```
# cd /usr/share/applications
# grep "Document Viewer" *.desktop
evince.desktop:Name=Document Viewer
```

The `evince.desktop` file contains `TryExec` and `Exec` line that points to the binary that we need.

```
TryExec=evince
Exec=evince %U
```

These entries are without a full path, so I take it that the underlying machinery will consult the runtime PATH to find the binary.